# Eraser tool in html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Hi i am building a  windows store app with html5 and javascript  in my app i am trying to  implement an eraser tool but this is problematic because if the user moves an image or another layer to where they've previously erased, they see the white drawing where they erased.
i have been  trying  to do the eraser tool from different ways for example i have changed  the default   globalCompositeOperation to "destination-out" like this  code

```
          //Here is the error.
        if (clickTool[j] == "eraser") {
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5);';
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5);';

        }
        else {
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            ctx.strokeStyle = clickColor[j];
        }
```

but unfortunately  it doesn´t work for me. i have  uploaded all my code to this link:

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/AHNxx/6/)

Please i would like to somebody could help me.

Thanks and i'm sorry for my speech , i'm mexican.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use multiple layers.** Have one canvas for the background image and another for the drawing; that why you never erase any of the background image.

If you need to, you can have multiple layers as they don't generally impact performance.

And of course if you can combine layers, say the last drawn squiggle to the background layer,  if you deem a drawing to be "permanent".

Comment: @OscarPerezMartinez No worries. Don't forget to accept if chosen answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a array of mid points. Use the globalCompositeOperation as 'destination-out' first  and 'source-over' later to make a transparent eraser trail .

Following is the code that you need to use with a mouse move function

```
var handleMouseMove = function (event) {
    midPt = new createjs.Point(oldPt.x + stage.mouseX>>1, oldPt.y+stage.mouseY>>1);

   if(curTool.type=="eraser"){

            var tempcanvas = document.getElementById('drawcanvas');
  var tempctx=tempcanvas.getContext("2d");
  tempctx.beginPath();
  tempctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";   
  tempctx.arc(midPt.x, midPt.y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);     
  tempctx.fill();
  tempctx.closePath();
  tempctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  drawingCanvas.graphics.clear();

  // keep updating the array for points 
  arrMidPtx.push(midPt.x);
  arrMidPty.push(midPt.y);
  stage.addChild(drawingCanvas);
  stage.update();

    }        

  };
```

I use this code to make a eraser that behaves like pen and fills up transparent color instead of white